# Can I drop second mention of "consists" when presenting percentage?

Tags: word-usage

Can I drop the second mention of the word "consists" (or any other similar verb) when presenting percentage?

For example, can I drop the highlighted words in the following statements?

> So far, about  95 percent of this structure consists of empty boxes,
> and only 5 percent **consists** of bricks.
>
> About 60 percent of chosen white rocks were used in the roof, while
> the other 40 percent **were used** in the foundation.
>
> Only about 35 percent of his work comprise valid research, while 65
> percent **comprise** redundant repetition.

Comment: You could consider rephrasing the sentences. For example _So far, about 95 percent of this structure consists of empty boxes whilst the rest is bricks._ **the rest** implies 5%

Comment: My question is why you are not thinking about the first ones. The 2 lower examples use the regular form in order to present percentage. Though upvoted.

Comment: @Kentaro - I am afraid I don't understand your question (_"My question is why you are not thinking about the first ones"_). Can you, please, elaborate?

Comment: @brilliant So your first example both uses the third person form. I don't understand why you are highlighting the "latter" form. (like **40 percent were used**.). In that example, the "first"one, "About 60 percent of chosen white rocks **were used**" line uses the second person form too.

Comment: You can omit the repetition in the first and third sentences (though I would use _consists of_ rather than _comprise_). I think that, if you omit the second _were used_, you need to omit _while_ as well.

Comment: @brilliant Are you asking whether when mentioning percentage 3rd person should be used or 2nd person be used, or are you asking "dropping"="omitting" as Kate Bunting says?

Comment: @KateBunting - I don't understand why you are talking about grammatical persons here in the firs place. I only highlighted those words in order to show which words I was asking about (that is, about the possibility of leaving them off).

Comment: @Kentaro - I understand the misunderstanding now. By _second "consists"_ I meant to say _the second word "consists"_. I will re-phrase my question now.

Comment: @KateBunting I don't also understand your logic. May be comma solves. "while, 40 percent in the foundation." sounds fine to me)

Comment: I would say it is perfectly alright to drop the second mention of the same word. However to make sense of the third sentence after dropping "comprise", you need to add "of" instead of "comprise". Also I support @PeterJennings suggestion of rephrasing the sentence so that you don't have to think of using the verb at all for the second instance of the sentence.

Comment: I never mentioned grammatical persons! To me, "...while the other 40% in the foundation" doesn't work as a phrase, though "60% were used in the roof, the other 40% in the foundation" is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So far, about 95 percent of this structure consists of empty boxes, and only 5 percent consists of bricks.

> About 60 percent of chosen white rocks were used in the roof, while the other 40 percent were used in the foundation.

> Only about 35 percent of his work comprise valid research, while 65 percent comprise redundant repetition.

We could remove the repeated words in all three examples and, if necessary to avoid confusion, add gapping commas at locations we have removed words.

http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/comma/gapping

Also, we usually do not place a comma to separate a subordinate clause from its independent clause if the latter comes first.  I have hence removed the commas before *while* in examples 2 and 3.

> So far, about 95 percent of this structure consists of empty boxes, and only 5 percent, of bricks.

> About 60 percent of chosen white rocks were used in the roof while the other 40 percent, in the foundation.

> Only about 35 percent of his work comprise valid research while 65 percent, redundant repetition.

We have a *joining comma* in example 1.  Some writers recommend changing such joining commas to semi colons for clarity, in view of the presence of gapping commas.